# Searchbox to URL in Javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, url

Okay, so I have this code

```html
<center>
<font color="blue">
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Admin Login
</h1>





<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckPassword() {
  var username=document.login.username.value;
  var password=document.login.password.value;
  location.href = username + password+'.htm';
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="ingen_javascript.htm" 
  onsubmit="CheckPassword();return false;" name="login">
<pre>
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
</pre>
<input type="submit" value="login" 
  onclick="CheckPassword();return false;">
</form>



<script language="javascript" text="javascript">
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+u", function() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("No"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("NO");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

and you can see that if you type anything on and click enter, it will come up with that in the URL. But how do I get rid of the password and just use the username but instead of 'Username:' it says 'vite:' and instead of 'login' it says 'go!'

Comment: You would benefit from reading an article I wrote about [spotting bad JavaScript tutorials](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/), your code demonstrates a number of the code smells I discus in it. Your code also demonstrates another outdated practice I need to add to it; falling back to `attachEvent` hasn't been necessary [since the time when IE8 was relevant](http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener).

Comment: To avoid downvotes in the future and improve your questions so you are more likely to get more and better answers to your questions, I would suggest reading [ask] and [mcve]. You'll get much better results if you follow their advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rereading your question and noticing the title hints that you are actually trying to use this code as some sort of searchable navigation instead of a "password" system like the original code, I've updated my answer.  I use a [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element to provide a list of suggested page names since you likely have a finite list of pages you want to be accessible this way rather than allowing arbitrary urls. The JavaScript then checks against that list so it only navigates to pages that actually exist.

```js
// get go and vite by thier id
var go = document.getElementById('go'),
  vite = document.getElementById('vite')
  // get all of the option elements inside of the pages datalist
  pages = document.querySelectorAll('#pages > option');

// convert the node list that querySelectorAll returned into a real array
pages = Array.prototype.slice.call(pages);

// convert pages from an array of element into an array of strings
// containing the value of each of the elements
pages = pages.map(function (item) {
  return item.value;
});

// goToSelectedPage should not be capitalized, in JS it is convention to
// only capitalize constructor functions
function goToSelectedPage () {
  var page = vite.value,
    url = page + '.htm';
  // if the value of vite is in the list of pages
  if (-1 !== pages.indexOf(page)) {
    console.log('Navigating to ' + url);
    // disabling the page change for this example
    //location.href = url;
  }
}

// attach the goToSelectedPage function to the click event on go
// All vaguely modern browsers support addEventListener,
// no need to check for it and fall back to attachEvent
go.addEventListener('click', goToSelectedPage, false);
// add an event listener to vite that will call goToSelectedPage
// if they press the enter key instead of clicking the Go! button
vite.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
  if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
    goToSelectedPage();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: blue; /* instead of wrapping the page in a font tag,
                  add the color to styling for the body */
}
.login-header {
  font-family: Comic Sans Ms;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="login-header">Admin Login</h1>
<label for="vite">Vite:</label> <input type="text" id="vite" list="pages"> <button id="go" type="button">Go!</button>
<!-- datalist is invisible but will be used by the vite element to provide an
auto complete suggestion list -->
<datalist id="pages">
  <option value="foo">
  <option value="bar">
  <option value="baz">
</datalist>
```

Instead of using inline styles and font tags, I moved the styling into a [`<style>` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) and gave the `h1` tag a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) that applies its styling. I removed the form since you aren't actually submitting a form. Using a `<button type="button">` instead of submit input will ensure that pressing the button by itself does not try to submit a form, causing navigation. I used [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get references to the `vite` and `go` elements and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll), which finds elements based on a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) string to grab the `option` elements. The list of option elements are then refined into a list of their values so we can search that list to confirm that a page exists before we try navigating to it.

**Other notes:**
You don't need to (and should not) use the `language` or `type` attribute on script tags, just use a bare `<script>` tag. Language has been deprecated for a long time and was never standardized. Type never really did anything either because a few different factors. Neither are needed, every browser that has ever supported the script tag defaults to JavaScript.

**Further reading:**

- [Introduction to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS)
- [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html) A great (and free) book about JS
- [Convert NodeList to Array](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array)
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- I wrote [Spotting bad JavaScript tutorials](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/) to help people who are learning JS; there are a lot of bad and/or outdated tutorials out there. A lot of beginners use that bad information unknowingly and develop bad habits. Knowing what to look out for can help you avoid things that may lead you to those bad habits.

---

For posterity I'll leave this here for anyone who is thinking about using code similar to the code in the question as a "password" system. Using something like [basic authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbAkQ05OSJo) would be a much better idea than using secret filenames. Someone will find those pages eventually. I've had search engines somehow find files that were never linked to anywhere! Don't count on an obscure filename to keep it private.